My email address I have on Play Store can't be verified due to spouse's death
My spouse passed away and his phone, that I no longer have, is my verification number for my email. I contacted Google and they sent me a code via my new email... then they cancelled the code because I'm still signed into my old email. I can't sign out of it or delete it without a verification code.
Need to use Google Play apps for work (and so much else) but it's all tied to the old email. Can't change to my new email UNTIL I verify the old one.
The questions, first, is there any way around this using the phone I have? Second, if not, if I get a new phone can I start fresh with my new email on Google Play?
ANY help is greatly appreciated.
PS: my verification email is long forgotten.

Why can't you just use the new email address? I mean, it will be a new start and everything will have to be setup again manually but it should work. If the old Google account is on the phone you are using, then can't you just open Gmail and get the email? I guess I am a little confused. But to answer you last question, yes, you can get a new phone and start over, or even factory reset the current one.

The Google account of your husband is part if your heritage, therefore you should be able to claim it no matter if you can access your husband's phone or not. You just have to prove to Google that you are the heiress.

@Robert ~ Thank you, but it's my account not my husbands. His old phone, which I no longer have access to, was my verification code phone.

@acejavelin ~ Thank you. I did make a new email... But can't sign out of the old one (that I'm locked out of) without a verification code... Google won't let me change my email address to my new one until I sign out of the old one. It's crazy!
That said, today I bought a new phone and am hoping to simply start over leaving the old, inaccessible email behind AND even the newer one I created... Made a 3rd email so I can truly, hopefully, just start over.

As mentioned by @Robert, you can claim your dead husband's account.
Fill in the form here

....
Make a request for a deceased person's account
We recognize that many people pass away without leaving clear instructions about how to manage their online accounts. We can work with immediate family members and representatives to close the account of a deceased person where appropriate. In certain circumstances we may provide content from a deceased user's account. In all of these cases, our primary responsibility is to keep people's information secure, safe, and private. We cannot provide passwords or other login details. Any decision to satisfy a request about a deceased user will be made only after a careful review.
Account Closure Requests
If you select to close the Google account, Google is unable to process any request to turn over the contents of the account at a later date. If you have already submitted a request for the contents of the account please wait for that request to be complete before submitting any subsequent requests.
What would you like to do?

Close the account of a deceased user
Submit a request for funds from a deceased user's account
Obtain data from a deceased user's account


